# Unmet dependencies for libgl1-mesa-dev while initializing build environment for android

Tags: 12.04, apt, android, ppa, mesa

I am trying to setup build environment on 
Ubuntu 12.04 (precise)(64bit). I am following the guide at [official android site](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html#installing-required-packages-ubuntu-1204). I encountered the following message.

```
$ sudo apt-get install  libgl1-mesa-dev
[sudo] password for buddy: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: mesa-common-dev (= 9.2.0~git20131002+9.2.2eb55601-0ubuntu0sarvatt~precise)
                   Depends: libdrm-dev (>= 2.4.45)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried installing mesa-common-dev

```
$ sudo apt-get install  mesa-common-dev
```

message

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mesa-common-dev : Depends: libdrm-dev (>= 2.4.45)
```

Then I tried installing

```
 $ sudo apt-get install libdrm-dev
```

message

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdrm-dev : Depends: libdrm2 (= 2.4.46-1ubuntu0.0.0.1) but 2.4.46+git20130702.c6d73cfe-0ubuntu0sarvatt~precise is to be installed
              Depends: libdrm-intel1 (= 2.4.46-1ubuntu0.0.0.1) but 2.4.46+git20130702.c6d73cfe-0ubuntu0sarvatt~precise is to be installed
              Depends: libdrm-radeon1 (= 2.4.46-1ubuntu0.0.0.1) but 2.4.46+git20130702.c6d73cfe-0ubuntu0sarvatt~precise is to be installed
              Depends: libdrm-nouveau1a (= 2.4.46-1ubuntu0.0.0.1) but 2.4.46+git20130702.c6d73cfe-0ubuntu0sarvatt~precise is to be installed
              Depends: libdrm-nouveau2 (= 2.4.46-1ubuntu0.0.0.1) but 2.4.46+git20130702.c6d73cfe-0ubuntu0sarvatt~precise is to be installed
              Depends: libkms1 (= 2.4.46-1ubuntu0.0.0.1) but 2.4.46+git20130702.c6d73cfe-0ubuntu0sarvatt~precise is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I tried the following steps mentioned here: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies) skipping the Disable/Remove/Purge PPAs part.

Answer (score -1):

Disable that PPA ... the version numbers indicate these are not Ubuntu archive packages ...

Comment: Can you please add steps to your answer. How to do that in my case and which ppa?